# MKLINK (symbolic link) not working

Tags: symbolic-link

I am trying to create a symbolic link on my Windows 10 64bit to redirect the iTunes backup file to my external hard disk (`D:\`)

This is the link I added in my command window:

```
mklink /J "%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "D:\iTunes Backup"
```

It didn't work fully as the backup file was still created in the parent directory (`C:\`) even though the same file was also created in `D:\`

Now I can't complete my phone backup because I do not have enough storage.

Why were two files created ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Why were two files created?

```
mklink /J "%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "D:\iTunes Backup"
```

The above command is broken. The syntax for `mklink` is:

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
```

where `link` is the "The new symbolic link name", so not the name of a directory including the full path.

In addition, you can't make a link where the name already exists.

If you were in directory `"%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync"` and you tried the command:

```
mklink /J Backup "D:\iTunes Backup"
```

Then you would have received an error:

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Note the error message says a file already exist instead of a folder. This is because the system sees links as shortcuts (files) and not as folders.

---

#### How do I redirect the iTunes backup file to my external hard disk?

Use the following procedure:

1. Create `D:\iTunes Backup` if it doesn't exist. Now you have a target for the junction:

   ```
   md D:\iTunes Backup
   ```
2. Go to the existing backup directory:

   ```
   cd "%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"
   ```
3. Move any existing files to `D:\iTunes Backup`:

   ```
   move * "D:\iTunes Backup"
   ```

   If there are any folders move those as well.
4. Go up one directory to `"%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\`:

   ```
   cd ..
   ```
5. Delete the backup directory:

   ```
   rd Backup
   ```
6. Create the junction:

   ```
   mklink Backup "D:\iTunes Backup"
   ```

   You should see a message like:

   > Junction created for Backup <<===>> D:\iTunes Backup

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your help.

I did received "Junction created for Backup <<===>> D:\iTunes Backup"

However, two files were created. One in my C:\ and one in my external hard disk D:\ - I'm not sure why?

Comment: I've no idea. There is not enough information in your question to even guess.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: I deleted the original back up file in my C:\ and created a new folder "itunes backup" in my D:\. 

Opened command window in \Apple Computer\MobileSync and entered:
mklink /J "%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "D:\iTunes Backup".

Got a message: Junction created for Backup <<===>> D:\iTunes Backup

After which I went ahead to back up my phone on itunes. A backup file was created in both my C:\ and D:\..

Comment: That is iTunes backup doing something weird. I've no idea how to fix it.

Comment: `mklink` is working exactly how it is supposed to. The problem is with iTunes backup not working correctly with junctions.

Comment: @michelleishigh You will see the backedup files in both paths: On D: drive, where the files reside and take up the disk space, and on C: drive in your `AppData`. Junction points are "transparent" for applications; Windows Explorer usually shows "shortcut"-like arrow on such folders but when you click it to open, it won't open the target folder like it does with real shortcuts. Thus if `...\MobileSync\Backup` is still a junction, everything works as expected.